# RecyclerView: почему в альбомной ориентации элементы выходят за границу экрана?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Возникла проблема при использовании RecyclerView.
Когда меняется ориентации на альбомную, я выставляю число столбцов = 2. Но вот правый столбец вылезает за границу экрана. 
Не знаю даже в чем проблема может быть
Holder создается вот так

```
 @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType)
        {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
```

разметка itema

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    ......
    </FrameLayout>
```

Тут инициализируется RecyclerView

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(getColumnCount(),  StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    adapter.setSelectionListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Comment: выходят за границу при запуске в альбомной, или после поворота?

Comment: в обоих случаях

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем у вас вес родительскому элементу в разметке указан. *** буду, в этом косяк)

Comment: нет, не в этом. я его добавил, чтобы проверить, не исчезнет ли данный баг

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что где-то внутри R.layout.item разметка так организована, что элементы не влезают в контейнер. Когда я использую RecyclerView, я сам считаю ширину вложенных элементов в зависимости от размеров экрана, полей и расстояний между элементами.